# Epic morphism prove (for small groups)

Tags: normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $G := ($[$\mathbb{Z}_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_group:Z4)$, +)$ and $N := ($[$\mathbb{Z}_2$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_group:Z2)$, +)$.

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, is $G \to G /N$ an epic morphism?

If yes, how can you prove this?

My attempt:

$G/N:=\{gN : g \in G\}$

Shouldn't this be:

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 + 0 = \{0, 1\} \\
\mathbb{Z}_2 + 1 = \{1, 2\} \\
\mathbb{Z}_2 + 2 = \{2, 3\} \\
\mathbb{Z}_2 + 3 = \{3, 0\} \\$$
?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to do it directly from the definition. More abstract proofs are also possible.

Comment: Take any element $g+N$ in the quotient. Can you find an element in $G$ which has image $g+N$?

Comment: Are you aware that surjective maps are epimorphisms ?

Comment: I've updated my question. Is this correct?

Comment: Not exactly. We have to take $\Bbb Z_2\cong N=\{0,2\}\subseteq\{0,1,2,3\}=\Bbb Z_4$. Then we find *two* cosets: $N=N+0=N+2=\{0,2\}$ and $N+1=N+3=\{1,3\}$.

Comment: Please post this as an answer!

Comment: What is the definition of EPIC morphism?